# Visibility of properties in scala class

Tags: java, scala, properties, visibility, scala-java-interop

I defined a property in the constructor of my class the following way:

```
class Step(val message:String = "")
```

When I try access to *message* value from Java code y get a visbility error. Why?

Comment: Probably a bug related to default&named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the @scala.reflect.BeanProperty annontation you get "automatic" **get** and **set** methods

See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/reflect/BeanProperty.html

```
scala> class Step(@scala.reflect.BeanProperty val  message:String )
defined class Step

scala> val s = new Step("asdf")
s: Step = Step@71e13a2c

scala> s.message
res6: String = asdf

scala> s.getMessage
res10: String = asdf
```

Comment: @isola009 The IDE plugin for Scala still has bugs, sometimes things like that happen. Same thing with the Scala plugins for NetBeans and Eclipse, they also sometimes show bogus errors.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, message should be public in this case, but for some reason it is not. So, as a WO you could make it private (just drop the "val") and find a way to produce a getter for this value:

```
class Step(message: String = ""){
  def getMessage() = message  
}
```

Or:

```
class Step(@scala.reflect.BeanProperty message: String = "")
```

And compile:

```
> scalac -cp . Step.scala
```

Then create the calling Java class:

```
public class SomeClass{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Step step = new Step("hello");
    System.out.println(" " + step.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Then compile and run:

```
> javac -cp . SomeClass.java
> java -cp "/home/olle/scala-2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease/lib/scala-library.jar:." SomeClass
hello
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that in the Java code you're trying to access the field with `step.message`. 
Indeed, there is such a field, and it is private. That is why you get the visibility error. When you declare 'val' fields in Scala, the compiler generates a field and accessor method. So in java you should use `step.message()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getMessage()`? Maybe scala is generating the accessor.